# Flutter: how to pass values from one file to another without Navigator?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, navigator

I having some troubles currently. I want to pass a String variable (the index of a list String) from one dart file to another but the only way I know is using Navigator. Any other ways to do so that also does not require the phone to change screens?

Comment: create a static variable or class or provider,

Answer (score 0):

```
    You can do it like this 
    {
//Model class that required some files to print out the full name
    class Model {
      String name;
      String fName;
      Model({required this.fName, required this.name});
     void caller(){
        print('Your name is: $name $fName');
     }
    }
    //This is data provider class to the Model class
    class Test {
    var  model = Model(fName: 'Flutter',name: 'Developer');
    
      
    }
    // This is the main function to Invoke the Test class
    void main() {
     
      var tester =Test();
      tester.model.caller();
    }
    
    }
```